# std::erase in C++

Tags: c++, list, stl, erase

I am confused about function of `std::erase` in C++.

The following code gets the same output before and after `std::erase` is called.But if iterate through the list after performing `std::erase` then in output the erased value is not showing.
Help me understand `std::erase`.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> v;
    v.push_back(12);
    v.push_back(10);
    v.push_back(20);

    list<int>::iterator it;
    it = v.begin();
    printf("%u %d\n", it, *it);
    v.erase(it);
    printf("%u %d\n", it, *it);

    for(it= v.begin(); it!= v.end(); it++)
        cout<< *it<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
"Memory address" 12  
"Memory Address" 12  
10 20
```

Comment: What's actually unclear from the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase)? Besides that your output doesn't render as you describe.

Comment: Also, [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: There is no `std::erase` in the standard library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`erase` invalidates the iterator you give it (plus potentially other ones, depending on the container).
Using and dereferencing this iterator afterwards is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ Standard relative to the class template list

> Effects: Invalidates only the iterators and references to the erased
>   elements.

Thus the program has undefined behavior.

After this statement

```
v.erase(it);
```

the iterator `it` that initially was set as

```
it = v.begin();
```

now does not correspond to `v.begin()` and the output of the loop

```
for(it= v.begin(); it!= v.end(); it++)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^         
    cout<< *it<<" ";
```

confirms that.

Instead of

```
v.erase(it);
```

you could write

```
it = v.erase(it);
```

and in this case the returned iterator will indeed correspond to the iterator returned by `v.begin()`